# Group By Rows Where Field is a Given Value

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I am currently running queries in MS Access but doing so using SQL and not the 'design window'. I'm still learning so some help would be much appreciated.

I **have** the following table (I have colour coded this to help):

[image]

I am looking to essentially do a 'Group By' statement on all the fields except CAP_REFERENCE, but returning only a unique set of values that share the same CAP_REFERENCE value (I have colour-coded this grouping in these example tables).

At the moment I can run the following 'Group By' statement to remove records with duplicate combinations of all fields. *NOTE: I'm aware that using a group by function I would have to max() (or similar) my CAP_REFERENCE so it's only taking the first possible value if there are multiple.*

```
SELECT FACULTY_CODE, UNIT_CODE, CLASS_CODE, CAPACITY, LOCATION, NEW, max(CAP_REFERENCE)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY FACULTY_CODE, UNIT_CODE, CLASS_CODE, CAPACITY, LOCATION, NEW
```

and I **get**:

[image]

Am I able to 'Group By' both rows so that the resulting table will be the following instead? (**what I really need instead**):

[image]

I have thought about maybe concatenating the rows where the CAP_REFERENCE is the same and putting them all in a new table and THEN doing a 'Group By' but then I wouldn't know how to separate all the values out again. The full table I am running this query on has 509 records so I definitely need to standardise the process.

I appreciate all ideas!

**EDIT Original table here so you guys don't have to type it out :)**

```
+------+------+-------+-------+---------+------+--------+
| col1 | col2 | col3  | col4  |  col5   | col6 |  col7  |
+------+------+-------+-------+---------+------+--------+
|  550 |    0 | ALERT | FULL  | OUTSIDE | NO   | ABC123 |
|  550 |    1 | ALERT | EMPTY | OUTSIDE | NO   | ABC123 |
|  550 |    0 | ALERT | FULL  | OUTSIDE | NO   | ABC456 |
|  550 |    1 | EVENT | EMPTY | OUTSIDE | NO   | ABC456 |
|  553 |    0 | ALERT | FULL  | OUTSIDE | NO   | ABC555 |
|  553 |    1 | EVENT | EMPTY | OUTSIDE | NO   | ABC555 |
|  553 |    0 | ALERT | FULL  | OUTSIDE | NO   | ABC888 |
|  553 |    1 | EVENT | EMPTY | OUTSIDE | NO   | ABC888 |
+------+------+-------+-------+---------+------+--------+
```

**EDIT**
Fixed the typos in the sample data, sorry!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle, https://dbfiddle.uk/. (I'm too lazy to type all that data, and I can't do copy-and-past since you provided images instead of formatted text.)

Comment: Interesting in real sql server where you can use CTEs, but a bit tricky in access which is a bit limited in what ou can do.

Comment: You also have a typo in your sample data - they are all ABC123

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @TomC all fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to filter out pairs of cap reference values where both rows "appear earlier" -- that is, have duplicates in all the other rows.

If this interpretation is correct, you can get the cap references using aggregation:

```
select t.CAP_REFERENCE
from tbl as t
where exists (select 1
              from tbl as t2
              where t2.FACULTY_CODE = t.FACULTY_CODE and
                    . . . and -- all the other conditions
                    t2.CAP_REFERENCE < t.CAP_REFERENCE
             )
group by t.cap_reference
having count(*) = 2;
```

Then these are the references you do *not* want.  So you can use a `left join`:

```
select t.*
from tbl as t left join
     (select t.CAP_REFERENCE
      from tbl as t
      where exists (select 1
                    from tbl as t2
                    where t2.FACULTY_CODE = t.FACULTY_CODE and
                          . . . and -- all the other conditions
                          t2.CAP_REFERENCE < t.CAP_REFERENCE
                   )
      group by t.cap_reference
      having count(*) = 2
     ) as tt
     on tt.CAP_REFERENCE = t.CAP_REFERENCE
where tt.CAP_REFERENCE is null;
```